# How to download files from a webpage that points to a directory?

Tags: files, wget, download

I'm trying to download all the .mp3 files from [here](http://freemusicarchive.org/genre/Composed_Music/); but the download links are not `.mp3` .

(ex:https://freemusicarchive.org/music/download/98281de10b6cc09df9e99a5a3bd2c7ee0eddaf82) links but a subfolder which holds the `.mp3`. How do you download those files?

Right now I'm using

```
wget --level=1 --wait=5 --directory-prefix=~/Music/Classical --user-agent=Mozilla --recursive --no-parent --accept mp3,MP3 freearchive.org/genre/Composed_Music/
```

And I'm receiving no response from the server.